# React: trigger onChange and update select element if input value is changed by state

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the input value according to state. The code below triggers the `handleChange()` method manually. This works for an input box, but I cannot figure out how to do this to also update a `select` box.

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
ev = new Event("option", { bubbles: true });
el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(node);
```

See full code below:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: "random text",
      country: "USA"      
    }
  }


  handleChange (node, value ) {

    if(typeof value === "object") {

        this.setState({
            country: value.target.value
        });

    } else {
        this.setState({value: 'another random text'})
    }

    var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
    this.myinput.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e)}} ref={(input)=> this.myinput = input}/>
        <select  onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e)}} name="country">
            <option>USA</option>
            <option>Mexico</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,  document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes:

**1.** Define a `name` property same as state variable name with both the fields, `input` and `select`.

**2.** Bind the change function inside constructor:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

**3.** Use `[]` to update the particular state variable in change function and access that state variable name by `e.target.name`.

**4.** You are using the `controlled input` element so `ref` is not required here, you can access `input` element value by `this.state.value`

Check the working snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: "random text",
      country: "USA"      
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange (e ) {
      this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input name='value' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <select name="country" value={this.state.country} onChange={this.handleChange} >
            <option>USA</option>
            <option>Mexico</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,  document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```